# VSCode Python Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Although I'm using type hinting for the structure of a dictionary, VSCode's Microsoft's intellisense engine seems not to recognize the class inside the dictionary.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
class MyClass():
    def myf(self, methods):
        foo = "bar"
        return foo

mystring: str
mydict: Dict[str: MyClass] = {}

# mydict[mystring].      # <--- after typing the point ".", I expected hints from intellisense.
# mydict[mystring].myf(  # <--- after typing the open "(", I expected function hints
# mydict[mystring].myf() # <--- pressing f12 when cursor is on "myf", I expected to jump to the definition of the function
```

None of my expectations were met. 
Am I doing something wrong?
Is this something not supported at all by Microsft's intellisense (language server or Jedi)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not as out-of-the box as I'd thought

1. You need [VSCode's Mypy extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matangover.mypy)
2. As per that link, for "hover" and "go to definition" functionalities you need to run the Mypy Language server with Python3.8

Answer (score 0):

I *am* getting all the indicated autocompletions and the F12 behaviour. (VSCode version 1.40, Python extension version 2019.10.44104, MPLS version 0.4.114.0), without a 3rd party extension.

For reference, per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2250#issuecomment-417795722) comment,

> We use type hints to help provide auto-completion/IntelliSense, not
>   linting/error detection against type hints. For the latter you should
>   install mypy.

Microsoft Python Language Server (MPLS) appears to have support for type hints for Intellisense. It does need to be enabled manually by setting `python.jediEnabled` to `False`. (They're working on flipping the default LS to MPLS in the ["next few releases"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-may-2019-release/)).

Maybe you were facing some MPLS issue which has since been fixed?